# Compare two images (Textures) for identity using Metal

Tags: swift, image, macos, textures, metal

I would like to find pairs of identical images in array of 50 millions (and more) of images. In Swift using CPU it wil take too much time and I have consider another option - massive parallel comparison of images on GPU using Metal (for macOS). Any advice how it can be done will be very helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to identify images that are 100% identical, pixel-for-pixel? It might be quicker to first compare the file size. If you're comparing images that are "identical" in content but may actually have different sizes, etc, then there are many existing algorithms for doing this quite quickly.

Comment: @Matthijs Hollemans All images have the same size, let say one row of 100 pixels in grey scale. The differences will be in values for each pixel. Yes, identity pixel-for-pixel.

Comment: Don't try to compare large arrays of images directly. Instead, compute a simple hash based on the contents of the data in the image and then compare the hashes.